# Diverging count of active users in the last 30 minutes (StreamView)

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I recently noticed that the user count that is shown on the map on the "StreamView" page is much lower than normal.
However, in the "Project Overview" tab, the same user count appears to be normal, as it is in accordance with the numbers that I had already obtained in my app's statistics.

When I click on that number of users online on the "Project Overview" page and I'm redirected to the map I see a completely different and much lower number...

This is happening with my 2 projects.

I took 2 screenshots to exemplify, one for each project. In both there are the two screens opened simultaneously to show the difference in the number of active users.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Reach out to Firebase support and file a bug, Mate!